# Add new entry to SQL Server database in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I am new to the forums and to programming in general, so this might be very obvious, but all I found out about this topic is how to create a new database via the Visual Studio Express (I am using version 2012 for windows Desktop) UI. I have already created the database and a new table, that contains the columns "id", "Username" and "Password".

Now I would like to add a new entry to this table when the user clicks a WPF button. Next to the button there is a Textbox with the username and a passwordbox for the password. When the new entry is added, it should use the data from these two boxes to fill in the corresponding columns. The ID should be increased automatically to the next higher value.

Later I want to be able to use the same two Boxes and another button to compare the entered information with the table in the database and grant the user access to other functions.

How can this be done?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Since I do not know anything about this and the internet refused to tell me the very basics I have not tried anything. There are some resources that look like they were right, but most of them are just a collection of methods without any context or explanation (this is one of the better pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.aspx).
So my basic problem is that I intend to do something way above my level and because of this I can not really try anything productive. Sorry, that's why I have to ask.

Comment: _So my basic problem is that I intend to do something way above my level..._ - There is your entire problem. Learn the language first, then the framework, then come back and ask questions. We're not here to teach, we're here to help you learn.

Comment: I did not ask for anyone to teach me, but I usually learn best when doing things I cannot do with my present knowledge. If I try to get better by gradually increasing the level, I just get bored and drop out. So asking this kind of question (or trying to find the answer myself) is my way of learning the language and the framework.

Comment: Your concept is flawed. Don't store passwords in the database. Store password hashes, preferably with a salt. If you google that, you'll find more information on this and why storing passwords is a bad idea.

Comment: Ah, wonderful, not what I was looking for but way better. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Read on SqlDataAdapter, SqlCommand, DataTable, and SqlCommand. These will help you get there.

Comment: Seems helpful, thanks. I will try to make some sense of them.